# Ionic 3: no component factory found,did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, node-modules

I've created an Angular library which has a few components and one module to export all. The module of this library is as follows:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstComponent } from './first';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProviderTest } from '../../providers/test/test'
import { SecondComponent } from '../second/second';
import { ThirdComponent } from '../third/third';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        FirstComponent,
        SecondComponent,
        ThirdComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FirstComponent,
        SecondComponent,
        ThirdComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        FirstComponent,
        SecondComponent,
        ThirdComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ComponentModule,
            providers: [ProviderTest]
        };
    }
}
```

My problem comes that when I try to use this library in my project, I get this:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for SecondComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

I've seen related questions where they say to add my `ComponentModule` to the declarations of the module where I want to use this library, but if I do that, I get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected module 'ComponentModule' declared by the module 'TestPageModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

The module of my `TestPageModule` is like this right now:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage,
    ComponentModule
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TestPage),
    ComponentModule
  ],
})
export class TestPageModule {}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? `SecondComponent` is a modal, just incase it's of any use. Also, this only happens when using lazy loading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using lazy loading and components , you should import your components in `app.module.ts` and also you should import the pages that uses this components 
so you should remove pages from other declarations and import them in `app.module.ts`

Comment: doesn't this make lazy loading totally useless?

Comment: well, just add the pages that uses the components not all pages

Answer (score 0):

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected module 'ComponentModule' declared by the module 'TestPageModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

`declarations` are only for `pipe`, `component` or `directive`. You should add `ComponentModule` only to the imports part of the module you want it to be used. Doing so, all exported components of the module will be availabe in `TestPageModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TestPage),
    ComponentModule
  ],
})
export class TestPageModule {}
```

Comment: this is how I had it since the begining but it gives me the first error I mention, it doesn't detect SecondComponent, which is a modal and created in runtime

Comment: if you remove `ComponentModule` in `TestPageModule` from `declarations` and remain it in `imports`, do you still have not `SecondComponent` available in `TestPageModule`?

Comment: exactly, i get the factory error mentioned in the question

Comment: Did you try to restart the app in the console?

Comment: yes, the way it works is if i also add it to add.module.ts , but i don't think this should be the way...